# Unity: Converting Texture2D to YUV420P and sending with UDP using FFmpeg

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, texture2d

In my Unity game each frame is rendered into a texture and then put together into a video using FFmpeg. Now my questions is if I am doing this right because avcodec_send_frame throws every time an exception. 
I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong or in the wrong order or simply missing something.

Here is the code for capturing the texture:

```
void Update() {
        //StartCoroutine(CaptureFrame());

        if (rt == null)
        {
            rect = new Rect(0, 0, captureWidth, captureHeight);
            rt = new RenderTexture(captureWidth, captureHeight, 24);
            frame = new Texture2D(captureWidth, captureHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        }

        Camera camera = this.GetComponent<Camera>(); // NOTE: added because there was no reference to camera in original script; must add this script to Camera
        camera.targetTexture = rt;
        camera.Render();

        RenderTexture.active = rt;
        frame.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0);
        frame.Apply();

        camera.targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = null;

        byte[] fileData = null;
        fileData = frame.GetRawTextureData();
        encoding(fileData, fileData.Length);

    }
```

And here is the code for encoding and sending the byte data:

```
private unsafe void encoding(byte[] bytes, int size)
    {
        Debug.Log("Encoding...");
        AVCodec* codec;
        codec = ffmpeg.avcodec_find_encoder(AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
        int ret, got_output = 0;

        AVCodecContext* codecContext = null;
        codecContext = ffmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
        codecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
        codecContext->width = captureWidth;
        codecContext->height = captureHeight;
        //codecContext->time_base.den = 25;
        //codecContext->time_base.num = 1;

        AVRational timeBase = new AVRational();
        timeBase.num = 1;
        timeBase.den = 25;
        codecContext->time_base = timeBase;
        //AVStream* videoAVStream = null;
        //videoAVStream->time_base = timeBase;



        AVRational frameRate = new AVRational();
        frameRate.num = 25;
        frameRate.den = 1;
        codecContext->framerate = frameRate;

        codecContext->gop_size = 10;
        codecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
        codecContext->pix_fmt = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

        AVFrame* inputFrame;
        inputFrame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();
        inputFrame->format = (int)codecContext->pix_fmt;
        inputFrame->width = captureWidth;
        inputFrame->height = captureHeight;
        inputFrame->linesize[0] = inputFrame->width;

        AVPixelFormat dst_pix_fmt = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, src_pix_fmt = AVPixelFormat.AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA;
        int src_w = 1920, src_h = 1080, dst_w = 1920, dst_h = 1080;
        SwsContext* sws_ctx;

        GCHandle pinned = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr address = pinned.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        sbyte** inputData = (sbyte**)address;
        sws_ctx = ffmpeg.sws_getContext(src_w, src_h, src_pix_fmt,
                             dst_w, dst_h, dst_pix_fmt,
                             0, null, null, null);

        fixed (int* lineSize = new int[1])
        {
            lineSize[0] = 4 * captureHeight;
            // Convert RGBA to YUV420P
            ffmpeg.sws_scale(sws_ctx, inputData, lineSize, 0, codecContext->width, inputFrame->extended_data, inputFrame->linesize);
        }

        inputFrame->pts = counter++;

        if (ffmpeg.avcodec_send_frame(codecContext, inputFrame) < 0)
            throw new ApplicationException("Error sending a frame for encoding!");

        AVPacket pkt;
        pkt = new AVPacket();
        //pkt.data = inData;
        AVPacket* packet = &pkt;
        ffmpeg.av_init_packet(packet);

        Debug.Log("pkt.size " + pkt.size);
        pinned.Free();
        AVDictionary* options = null;
        ffmpeg.av_dict_set(&options, "pkt_size", "1300", 0);
        ffmpeg.av_dict_set(&options, "buffer_size", "65535", 0);
        AVIOContext* server = null;
        ffmpeg.avio_open2(&server, "udp://192.168.0.1:1111", ffmpeg.AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, null, &options);
        Debug.Log("encoded");
        ret = ffmpeg.avcodec_encode_video2(codecContext, &pkt, inputFrame, &got_output);
        ffmpeg.avio_write(server, pkt.data, pkt.size);
        ffmpeg.av_free_packet(&pkt);
        pkt.data = null;
        pkt.size = 0;
    }
```

And every time I start the game

```
  if (ffmpeg.avcodec_send_frame(codecContext, inputFrame) < 0)
            throw new ApplicationException("Error sending a frame for encoding!");
```

throws the exception.
Any help in fixing the issue would be greatly appreciated :)